How to merge and match different length dataframes (lists) in Python/Pandas
I have over 12 dataframes that I want to merge into a single dataframe, where row values match for each column (or null if they don't exist). Each dataframe has a different number of rows, but will never repeat values. The goal is to both identify common values and missing values.
Eg.df1
id  label
1   a-1  
2   b-2  
3   z-10  

Eg.df2
id  label
1   b-2  
2   d-4  
3   e-5

Eg.df3
id  label
1   a-1
2   d-4  
3   f-6

Desired output
Eg.final
id  df1  df2  df3
1   a-1  null a-1
2   b-2  b-2  null 
3   null d-4  d-4
4   null e-5  null
5   null null f-6
6   z-10 null null

I've investigated join, but these all seem to collapse values. insert seemed plausible, but I can't rectify the different row sizes/matching values to the same row.
I want to maintain each df as it's own column.

For multiple dataframes, you can use merge with reduce:
from functools import reduce

reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on='label', how='outer'), 
       map(lambda d: d[1].drop(columns='id')
                         .assign(**{ f'df{d[0]}':lambda x: x['label'] }), 
           enumerate(dfs, 1)) 
      ).assign(id=lambda x:range(1, 1+len(x))).drop(columns='label')     # this is just to drop the existing `label` and assign new `id`

Out:
    df1  df2  df3  id
0   a-1  NaN  a-1   1
1   b-2  b-2  NaN   2
2   NaN  d-4  d-4   3
3   NaN  e-5  NaN   4
4   NaN  NaN  f-6   5
5  z-10  NaN  NaN   6

Another method is join on the index, like:
renamed_dfs = list(map(lambda d: d[1].drop(columns='id')
                                     .assign(**{ f'df{d[0]}':lambda x: x['label'] })
                                     .set_index('label'),
                       enumerate(dfs, 1)
                   ))
renamed_dfs[0].join(renamed_dfs[1:], how='outer').reset_index(drop=True).reset_index()

Output:
   index   df1  df2  df3
0      0   a-1  NaN  a-1
1      1   b-2  b-2  NaN
2      2  z-10  NaN  NaN
3      3   NaN  d-4  d-4
4      4   NaN  e-5  NaN
5      5   NaN  NaN  f-6


Thank you! I completely forgot this would be an outer join.

I would use a simple concat:
from natsort import natsort_key

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

out = (pd.concat({f'df{i}': d.set_index(d['label'])['label']
                  for i, d in enumerate(dfs, start=1)}, axis=1)
        .sort_index(key=natsort_key)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
      )
out.insert(0, 'id', np.arange(len(out))+1)

Output:
   id   df1  df2  df3
0   1   a-1  NaN  a-1
1   2   b-2  b-2  NaN
2   3   NaN  d-4  d-4
3   4   NaN  e-5  NaN
4   5   NaN  NaN  f-6
5   6  z-10  NaN  NaN

